# How do I run some code whenever a BigQuery table is updated?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to run some PySpark code whenever a BigQuery table is updated?

I have something similar running whenever a file is uploaded to Google Cloud Storage using Cloud Functions but I can't find anything in the BigQuery documentation that offers similar functionality.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Check this blog: https://www.e-nor.com/blog/bigquery/cloud-functions-bigquery-data-feed-automation

Comment: There is no native support in BigQuery for calling calling Cloud Functions or emitting event to Pub/Sub. Like the comment above calls out (via the blog post), you need to hook into BigQuery's events via Stackdriver. Here's another resource/blog about it. **Disclaimer: I wrote it.** https://polleyg.dev/posts/bigquery-new-tables-dlp/

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no BigQuery trigger for Google Cloud Functions, however this feature is currently in progress and should be launched soon (as of June 2019).